# Orchard CMS 1.4: Adding a Text Field to Custom ContentPart

Tags: orchardcms

In the module for a custom ContentPart, how do I set a field to be a Text field?

In my migrations.cs class, I have created the table for the part:

```
public int UpdateFrom1()
        {
            SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("RightContentPartRecord", table =>
               table.ContentPartRecord()
                    .Column<string>("Html"));                                                      
            return 2;
        }
```

So, I have a column called Html.  I want to use the WYSIWYG editor, so I am told I need a Text field to get this to work "out of the box".

However, this isn't happening for me, so what do I need to do to turn my column called Html into a Text field on the part?

And how do I configure it to use the WYSIWYG editor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A text field is not the same thing as a part property. Fields are not stored as their own database column. Here is an example of how you add a field to a part from a migration:

```
        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("Product",
          builder => builder.WithField("ProductImage", fieldBuilder => fieldBuilder.OfType("MediaPickerField").WithDisplayName("Product Image")));
```

For text field, you'd also need to set the flavor setting by adding `.WithSetting("Flavor", "html")` to the field builder.

Comment: thanks I had got there, my problem now is that as the Field is not part of the model for the part, it is in consequence not part of the shape.  So when I try to place the part (using Pete Hurst's ZoneProxy code), it turns out the field is part of a different shape with a generic name, so doesn't place.  Is there a way to make the field part of the shape?  Or control the Field's shape name so that I can precisely place it individually (and not place all the other Field shapes on the page with the same name, eg, Field_Common_Text)?

Comment: Or is there a way to make a Field a Part Property, so that it shares the shape...

Comment: No. It's not a field that you need then. Look at how the Body part is built and copy it to yours.

Comment: Sorry, I have looked, but can't find where the Body part is built, could you point me at it?  Thanks

Comment: @awrigley couldn't you place the field as part of placement.info file anyway?  <Place Fields_Common_Text-MyFieldName="/ZoneName:1"/> (or am i misunderstanding what you're trying to do?)

Comment: And also a note that I think the Part you are modifying must match the Content Type name; for example, if you want to add fields to a content type called Fruits, you need to .AlterPartDefinition("Fruits", ...) - anything else seems to give an exception when you activate the module

Comment: and it's no longer .WithSetting("Flavor", "html") but .WithSetting("TextFieldSettings.Flavor", "html") - http://henry-chong.com/2013/03/orchard-cms-adding-a-field-to-a-custom-content-type-in-your-module-migrations-cs/

Answer (score 8):

If you want a property of your own custom contentpart to be displayed as a htmleditor, configure it as follows in the editortemplate of your part.

```
@Script.Require("OrchardTinyMce")
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Header, new { @class = "html tinymce" })
```

In this case the 'Header' property is displayed as a html editor.

If you need this in more parts you can consider writing a Html extension or editor template for it.

Comment: This is excellent, works well for arbitrary `string` properties on a part. One slight "gotcha" for me though, I had to define javascript vars `mediaPickerEnabled` and `mediaLibraryEnabled` *before* the call to `@Script.Require` to keep the TinyMce script happy.

Comment: (BTW for future readers, I have this working on a 1.7.2 install)