# Add Body Part to Custom Widget - Placement

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

This time I'm struggling with my custom widget for Orchard.
It's a simple content part with two fields:
- Background Color
- Size

I want to be able to add HTML content to this widget; so I added the Body Part. This part must be displayed within my widget. The result should be something like this:

`<div class="size-small bg-color-red"> BODY PART HTML CONTENT </div>`

But unfortunately, the Body Part is always displayed *before* or *after* my widget.

```
<Placement>
    <Place Parts_ContentTile="Content"/>
    <Place Parts_ContentTile_Edit="Content:7.5"/>
</Placement>
```

**Not so nice 'solution':**
A way to resolve this is to remove the body part and replace it with a simple text field. This text field is rendered at the desired position. But then the TinyMCE Editor is not available.

**Update after comment from Ivan:**
I tried to change both (Content Type and Content Part (separate)) but unfortunately, both times, the TextField content is displayed after the widget. Should that be fixed in the Placement.info?

Another option is to add a String field to my Widget Model. But then it is not possible to show the TinyMCE editor. Am I right?

So I've got the feeling that my expectations about widgets, content parts and placements are incorrect. Hopefully somebody here can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13698360/267122) from [Mark Z](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1874947/mark-z) was really helpfull to me!

I added a String property to my Model and added a new Database Migration:

```
public int UpdateFrom3()
{
   // Adds a new Content column
   SchemaBuilder.AlterTable("ContentTileRecord", table => table.AddColumn("Content", DbType.String));

   return 4;
}
```

After that I added the field to the Editor Part View:

```
@Script.Require("OrchardTinyMce")

<div class="editor-label">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content)
</div>

<div class="editor-field">
   @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Content, new { @class = "html tinymce" }) 
</div>
```

The Content Property is now displayed as a TextArea. Because of the classes 'html and tinymce' the TinyMCE editor is instantiated. (Don't forget the Script.Require call)

Because of the fact that the Content property contains HTML, it is required to use the @Html.Raw helper to display the value of this property.

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Content)
```

Answer (score 2):

When using `TextField`, you can use `TinyMCE` by specifying `HTML flavor` in the settings of the field.

To do that you can go to <kbd>Content</kbd> → (<kbd>Content Types</kbd> or <kbd>Content Parts</kbd> depending on which you are trying to change) → Select your `ContentType` or `ContentPart` → Expand the definition of the `TextField` you're using → Select <kbd>HTML</kbd> from the drop down menu next to `Flavor` → Click on <kbd>Save</kbd> button.

Comment: I tried to change both (Content Type and Content Part (separate)) but unfortunately, both times, the TextField content is displayed after the widget. Should that be fixed in the Placement.info?

Comment: Yes, you should use combination of adding `TextField` with `HTML flavor` and setting its position through `Placement.info` if you want it to be placed elsewhere..

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. But how do I display the TextField in my widget cshtml? @Model.[FieldName] ?